# Passing a single row in a 3D array to function

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct

I am trying to pass a row of a multidimensional array to a function as pointer. The 3d arrays are stores inside the following structure.

```
typedef struct{
double complex CUR[MAX_CHANNELS][MAX_HARM][4];
double complex VOL[MAX_CHANNELS][MAX_HARM][4];
}VALS;
```

I am trying to pass one row into the following function as a parameter.

```
void foo(double complex *V,double complex *I);
```

In the main program I am passing the first row as a pointer. But in the execution I am getting an "incompatible pointer type warning".

```
foo(&VALS.VOL[2][0],&VALS.CUR[2][0]);
```

Comment: You don't need `&`. Arrays automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since the third dimension is still an array, the resulting type of `vals.VOL[2][0]` and `vals.CUR[2][0]` is of type `double*` (pointing to the first element of the array). therefore a  `&` is not needed:

```c
foo(vals.VOL[2][0], vals.CUR[2][0]);
```